# detect one subview on top of another subview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I am trying to detect one subview when dragged on top of another subview to see if it collides. What is a good way to do that? I am using UIPanGestureRecognizer for dragging the elements.  thanks

Comment: Thanks @Bavarious, I will use Cocoa Touch tags next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `CGRectIntersectsRect()` for doing the task:

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(firstSubview.frame, secondSubview.frame))
{
   //collides, do your task here
}
```