# Swift detect if UICollectionViewCell is dragged on top of another UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` with just 1 section and many cells in that section. I've enabled drag and drop behavior (with a long press gesture recognizer, because the `UICollectionView` sits in a generic `UIViewController`).

I'd like the **drag and drop behavior to detect when the dragged cell is over the top of another cell**. Google search didn't yield anything helpful, but Stackoverflow has [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071548/detect-one-subview-on-top-of-another-subview). While I can try to implement that by writing something similar in the `UIViewController` class to check if the dragged cell's Rect intersect with *every other cell*, I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I think you could just grab the min and max X or Y coordinates (depending on whether the collection view is horizontal or vertical) of the dragged view, and then do a binary search through the views in the collection until you find one that intersects. This way, you wouldn't have to test all the views.

EDIT: Adding an example to clarify what I mean. Suppose we have a collection of views that are arranged left-to-right:

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

We start by getting the min and max X values of our dragged view. We'll call those "minX" and "maxX". We start by looking at the view in the middle of our list, view 5. If maxX < view 5's min X, then the view we're looking for has to be one of 0...4. If minX > view 5's min X, then we're looking for something in 6...10. Otherwise view 5 is intersecting the dragged view in the horizontal dimension.

After testing view 5, we test either view 2 or view 8, depending on whether the dragged view is to the left or right of view 5. We continue via this method until we happen upon an overlapping view, and each time we test a view we eliminate half of the views from consideration, so it will perform better than having to test every view in the collection.

Once you find one view that overlaps the dragged view, you'll want to check the adjacent views to see if they also overlap. In the case where the dragged view overlaps with several other views, you'll have to choose the one that overlaps the greatest area.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.